# view total number of columns where per character in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, settings, customization

I don't know what the correct term is for this, but I would like to be able to view all column numbers of the text in sublime text simultaneously. Basically it would be the same as sublime text does by default showing the number of lines in the file, but I wanted to see the number of columns.

The image below shows what I'm looking for, but the column numbers in red can be in the top margin of course, it's just an example:

[image]

Note: I have placed spaces between characters horizontally in my example image for better visualization, pretend these spaces don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no [published plugins](https://packagecontrol.io/search/column) for that kind of functionality that I'm aware of. By default, you can see what row and column the cursor is on in the lower left corner of the window, on the status bar.

[image: screenshot showing line/column display in status bar]

Other than that, the only solution I can think of is to have a line of numbers repeating 1-0, maybe changing the first number every ten digits:

```
1234567890123456789212345678931234567894...
```